# What is the environment variable for passing options to the python interpreter when running pyspark?

Tags: python, pyspark, environment-variables, ipython

There is an environment variable for passing extra options to the python interpreter when invoking `pyspark`.  What is this variable?

```
$> PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython <WHAT_NAME_HERE?>="--pylab" pyspark
```

It's not mentioned in the [official docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/configuration.html), but I know it exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS`, sensibly enough.

Comment: You should have mentioned which version of pyspark you were using. You implied it was 2.2.0 via your link to the pyspark documention. Which is pretty old (if not temporarily then by number of releases) compared to the current version. Too, you should have mentioned in your answer which pyspark version that env var was introduced.

Comment: That's definitely not the only one. There's also PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS, among others